# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect, Getting this error while starting elasticsearch.bat?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute batch file of elasticsearch. I am getting this error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
    I ran it without @echo off and saw this `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %ES_JAVA_OPTS% %ES_PARAMS% %* -cp "%ES_CLASSPATH%" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch"` of the bat file producing error.

On command line it tries to execute `E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1\bin>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -Delasticsearch -Des-foreground=yes -Des.path.home="E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1"  -cp ";E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch-1.0.1.jar;E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/*;E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/sigar/*" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -Delasticsearch -Des-foreground=yes -Des.path.home="E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1"  -cp ";E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/elasticsearch-1.0.1.jar;E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/*;E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib/sigar/*" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch"`

I am running it from E:\Toshiba\elasticsearch-1.0.1/lib where the elasticseach.bat is there

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is probably set improperly (it should just be a single directory).

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin\java"` Is not a valid path.